# Completely broken front and back-end, after copy files and DB to create copy of live store

Tags: frontend, development

To create copy of live store for developing,

Copied files (except some product files) / Import db from live site / Delete all www/var/

UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com/"; WHERE path=’web/secure/base_url’;

UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com/"; WHERE path=’web/unsecure/base_url’;

Live site work well but my test site's front-end and back-end completely broken , show only text like

[image]

- Update : just found, when I changed language to English (my default language is not English) the front-end works well , loading all theme , seems fine, but when I change language from English to Korean again, front-end is still broken
- Magento 1.8.1

On the broken admin page (like screenshot), when I click 'Sales - Orders', this error show up

```
There has been an error processing your request
Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/i/n/inn122-kr....')
#1 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(1824): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'thumbnail')
#2 /home/testsite/www/app/code/local/Amasty/Ogrid/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid/Renderer/Images.php(23): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->getThumbnailUrl()
#3 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): Amasty_Ogrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Renderer_Images->render(Object(MW_Onestepcheckout_Model_Sales_Order))
#4 /home/testsite/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(MW_Onestepcheckout_Model_Sales_Order))
#5 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(244): include('/home/playfirst...')
#6 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(275): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(289): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#12 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#13 /home/testsite/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#14 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(244): include('/home/playfirst...')
#15 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(275): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(289): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#20 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#24 /home/testsite/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#25 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(244): include('/home/playfirst...')
#26 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(275): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(289): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#34 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /home/testsite/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /home/testsite/www/index.php(139): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}
```

Comment: Looks like your css is not loading. I would check the urls set in admin/database. Also check if files are on system.

Comment: _except some product files_ Hmm, what files exactly? Images, program code?

Comment: @FiascoLabs exclude -- www/media/import/* and www/media/catalog/product/* I will remove all and try to copy files and import DB later again to see the same issue happen again

Comment: You will be missing **all product image files** if you exclude `media/catalog/product/*` and since the reference to those files still exists in the database, Magento is going to throw a massive error about the original image file not being found when you go into product maintenance in the backend. Only exclude `media/catalog/product/cache/*` when you transfer, you do want the base image files Magento uses to create the cached files.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Wow I didn't know that I will try again soon! You can reply your comment as answer I will let you know the result later Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting line of thought for the plaintext display when running the Korean template

First, shut off CSS and Javascript merge and clear their cache to see if that's causing the issue.

For some reason the Korean template isn't allowing the CSS to be read from the `skin/` subfolders created for it. Do a view text on the broken page and see where it's trying to pull the CSS files from and check to see if they exist in the location it wants.

---

Answer for the stack trace error cause.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /home/testsite/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/i/n/inn122-kr....')
```

**Note:** => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('**/i/n/inn122-kr....**')

You will be missing all product image files if you exclude `media/catalog/product/*` and since the reference to those files still exists in the database, Magento is going to throw a massive error about the original image file not being found when you go into product maintenance in the backend.

Only exclude `media/catalog/product/cache/*` when you transfer, you do want the base image files Magento uses to create the cached files.

Comment: Finally..! I made it You're right I shut off CSS Javascrupt merge, disable FPC and it works! So glad! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct values for these rows from DB:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'
```

Comment: I already did UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com" WHERE path=’web/secure/base_url’;

UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com" WHERE path=’web/unsecure/base_url’;

(also checked select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%')

Comment: It should be with `http://` at the start and with `/` at the end

Comment: Above are just example Just checked again both secure and unsecure address are clearly have http:// and / Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also check this:
`select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/web/unsecure/base_skin_url'`

All these keys:
web/unsecure/base_js_url,
web/unsecure/base_link_url,
web/unsecure/base_media_url,
web/unsecure/base_skin_url,
web/unsecure/base_url

should be set correctly

Comment: checked it's '{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/' , since unsecure_base_url is correct it seems the base_skin_url setting is right?

Comment: yes, it is right

Comment: When I copied from live site, I didn't edit other url excep secure and unsecure. so I think all other url setting like js, link and etc are correct

Comment: Press Ctrl+U and check what style paths do you have. And check if there are css files in the file system